# SQL Query to partition the records based on dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement where in I am suppose to exclude certain records based on data in two tables. The requirement is that a product is included for a certaiun period and then it is excluded for two different period. I have to come up with the final table which tells for which range the product is actually included.
I have tried multiple queries but of no luck.

```
Declare @DtlInc table
(prod varchar(32),
eff_dt date,
end_dt date
)

Declare @DtlExclu table
(prod varchar(32),
eff_dt date,
end_dt date
)

Insert into @pgDtlInc values ('A','01/01/2013','12/31/8888')
Insert into @pgDtlExclu values ('A','01/01/2012','12/31/2015')
Insert into @pgDtlExclu values ('A','01/01/2018','12/31/2020')


Final Data(Included) :
A   01/01/2016 12/31/2017
A   01/01/2021 12/31/8888
```

TIA

Amit

Answer (score 0):

This can be a challenging problem.  Here is one approach which breaks out the dates into a separate row for each one, along with an indictor of whether the date implies being "included" or "excluded".

Then, take the cumulative sum of this flag.  The cumulative sum now breaks the dates into groups, which are separated by zero values.  When aggregating by this group (and `prod`), you can get the periods of inclusion:

```
with pd as (
      select prod, eff_dt as dt, 1 as inc
      from @DtlInc
      union all
      select prod, end_dt, -1 as inc
      from @DtlInc
      union all
      select prod, eff_dt, -1 as inc
      from @DtlExclu
      union all
      select prod, end_dt, 1 as inc
      from @DtlExclu
     ),
     pdcume as (
      select pd.*, pdc.cumeinc
      from pd outer apply
           (select sum(inc) as cumeinc
            from pd2
            where pd2.prod = pd.prod and
                  pd2.dt <= pd.dt
           ) pdc
     ),
     pdg (
      select pd.*, pdg.grp
      from pd outer apply
           (select count(*) as grp
            from pdcume pdcume2
            where pdcume2.prod = pdcum.prod and pdcume2.dt < pd.dt and
                  pdcume2.cumeinc = 0
           ) pdg
     )
select prod, min(dt) as startdate, max(dt) as enddate
from pdg
group by prod;
```

Note:  this logic should work when the dates are different, although there might be off-by-one errors, depending on whether the end dates are inclusive or exclusive.  This problem is even more tricky when there are duplicate dates.  It is a bit easier to represent using the enhanced functionality in SQL Server 2012+, so this might be a good reason to upgrade to a more recent version of the database.

Comment: Thanks for that. really appreciate. however we can have same dates as well.
Insert into pgDtlInc values ('A','01/01/2013','12/31/8888')
Insert into pgDtlExclu values ('A','01/01/2012','12/31/2015')
Insert into pgDtlExclu values ('A','01/01/2018','12/31/8888')
In the above case A will be valid only from 2016-2018